# What file contains the Default Search Engine of Google Chrome? And where is this file stored?

Tags: google-chrome

What file contains the Default Search Engine of Google Chrome? And where is this file stored?

For some reason, Chrome keeps changing the default Browser to Yahoo
once a month.

I can't find what is the cause.
So I was thinking to make a cmd script
that will be executed on every start-up of Windows
and will enter Google, as the default search engine,
directly to the file (or DB) that the setting is stored in.

I've seen some solutions on Stack Overflow but now they
all are outdated...

I would really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some sort of malware or "search assistant" add-in that may be doing this, or regularly visiting a website that does it? I have and use Chrome heavily on all my computers, but with no search-related add-ins, and I never see my default search engine mysteriously changing.

Comment: I've "googled" my issue, and I am not the only one. Yes, the most solution are removing some plugin, or to scan your PC. I did all of that and still it happens. I am not sure that just visiting a website may cause this to happen. Does websites have such a permission? So i assume there is some malware on PC that is well hidden. But i can't find it. So... the solution I thought of is the one that I've posted here. It does not happen to often so ok, its not a big deal, but it would be nice to get rid of it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The file that contains the custom and default search engines is called "Web data"

And it is located in
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\